# How to optimize jQuery code for adding classes (to different elements)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Example HTML** (for the sake of clarity):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="top-navbar-channels">
            <a href="#"></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">BLAH, BLAH, BLAH!</div>
        </li>

        <li class="top-navbar-about">
            <a href="#"></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu-about">BLAH, BLAH, BLAH!</div>
        </li>

        <li class="top-navbar-search">
            <a href="#"></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu-search">BLAH, BLAH, BLAH!</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Example jQuery code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.dropdown-menu').on('show', function () {
        $('.top-navbar-channels > a').addClass('selected');
    });
    $('.dropdown-menu').on('hide', function () {
        $('.top-navbar-channels > a').removeClass('selected');
    });

    $('.dropdown-menu-about').on('show', function () {
        $('.top-navbar-about > a').addClass('selected');
    });
    $('.dropdown-menu-about').on('hide', function () {
        $('.top-navbar-about > a').removeClass('selected');
    });

    $('.dropdown-menu-search').on('show', function () {
        $('.top-navbar-search > a').addClass('selected');
    });
    $('.dropdown-menu-search').on('hide', function () {
        $('.top-navbar-search > a').removeClass('selected');
    });

});
```

**For those who are curious...** the jQuery code adds a new class `selected` to the active menu item's link. In my case it's [Twitter Bootstrap-based collapsible menu](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse), where active means, the menu item is not collapsed i.e. open.

Now, the question is, can the jQuery code be optimized (i.e. same functionality with less code)? If so, how?

Comment: Looking at last top li, I doubt top-navbar-channels would be top-navbar-menu ?

Comment: @Adil All menus (`li`) are horizontally placed using `float` CSS property. The first menu is floated `left` white the other two are floated `right`, and hence the change in order. Anyway, since it's unnecessary, I edit the code and remove the complexity. ;) **EDIT:** Or were you referring to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a common class to common  main elements so you can use that single class as the selector. You can also combine the events into one `on()` call and use `toggleClass()` on the link. `on()` allows for multiple space separated events

Example

```
<div class="dropdown-menu menu_content">
```

Then for jQuery:

```
$('.menu_content').on('show hide', function () {
        $(this).siblings("a").toggleClass('selected'); 
});
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion + answer. I hope @SamuelCaillerie doesn't mind. Thanks a lot, both of you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $menus = $('.dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu-search, .dropdown-menu-about');

    $menus.on('show', function () {
        $(this).siblings("a").addClass('selected'); // or alternatively, $(this).prev("a")
    });
    $menus.on('hide', function () {
        $(this).siblings("a").removeClass('selected'); // idem as above
    });
});
```

Comment: and to simplify the selector add an additional common class to all the main `LI` and just use that class in selector

Comment: @its_me Example: `<div class="dropdown-menu menu_content">` then `var $menus=$('.menu_content')`

Comment: We can also perhaps use : `$menus = $("nav > ul > li > div")`.

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie  sure...numerous ways to shorten selector. Using common class is my preference in larger pages for readibility

Answer (score -1):

This is a little shorter then Matthias... not very much shorter

```
$(function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu-search, .dropdown-menu-about').on('show',function(){
    $(this).siblings('a').addClass('selected');
  }).on('hide',function(){
    $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Comment: This won't work since the `a` link is not included in the div which is selected (`$(this).find("a")` will return nothing).

Comment: Sorry, i meant .siblings instead of .find. But Matthias gave you already a good answer :-)